# Maven is not running my mockito tests when deployment

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit, deployment, mockito

There are mockito tests in my project. I want to deploy my project but maven is not running some my tests when deployment.

[image]

**This is my deploy view.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Before, I have faced same problem. I don't know your pom.xml but when i add this dependency it worked. If you don't already have this in your pom.xml, you can give it a try.